# Networkx: How to remove single direction edges?

Tags: python, networkx

Suppose I have edges between `[(1,2),(2,1),(1,3)]`, how can I remove `(1,3)` since it is not bidrectional like the edge between 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a DiGraph.  In that case, first find the edges you want to remove.  Then remove them.

```
to_remove = [(v,u) for v,u in G.edges() if not G.has_edge(u,v)]
G.remove_edges_from(to_remove)
```

The list `to_remove` has all those edges in `G` for which `G` does not have the opposite edge (it is a list comprehension).

Answer (score 0):

This one is a little more lengthy, but don't modify the edges directly

```
import networkx as nx

# create the graph
G = nx.DiGraph()   
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,1),(1,3),(4,1),(1,5),(1,6),(5,1)])

H = nx.difference(G.to_undirected().to_directed(), G) # get the uni-directional edges
G = nx.difference(G, H.to_undirected())               # get the difference graph
G.edges()
# [(1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 1), (5, 1)]
```